# How to retrieve the events from Calendar when using the $expend parameter in MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to get the events in the a specific user's calendar by using the MS Graph API. I have used the API `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$expend=events`, However, it does not work. The events collection is null. And there are some event in my calendar.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the events in a specific user's calendar.

Based on my test, we can use the following code:

`public async Task<ICollection<Event>> EventsAsync(string calendarId)
{
    var events = await _serviceClient.Me.Calendars[calendarId].Events.Request().GetAsync();
    return events.CurrentPage;
}`

As the event is a relationships of the calendar, so the event will be null when we request a calendar. However, according to this document:

```
Note: Not all relationships and resources support the $expand query parameter. For example, you can expand the directReports, manager, and memberOf relationships on a user, but you cannot expand its events, messages, or photo relationships. Not all resources or relationships support using $select on expanded items
```

So we need request the `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/events`endpoint